# Handling Chinese Character in ODI 12c

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

How Should we handle Chinese Character in ODI12c?
While loading data from file to table chinese  Characters are loading as ?? at target side I have changed in JDBC url UTF8 but still not able to process Chinese  Characters  in ODI12c

Comment: your url should contain UTF-8 instead of UTF8!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JDBC should contain: useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8.

Example:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

It's similar for Oracle, by changing the connection details.